# XAML designer shows error after program has run and does not display correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xaml-designer

I have a weird error that the XAML designer displays when hovering over the text that gets the blue underline. It also refuses to show the components correctly in the preview. The text is simply

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

That looks like a `NullReferenceException`, but I have no clue where it comes from. It displays correctly in the launched app.

**It actually seems to be related to inheriting from `List<string>` AND exposing a settable property.** If I remove either of that it works. But I want both for my converter.

To reproduce it, simply create an empty WPF .NET Framework project, and paste this below the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` code inside the namespace:

```csharp
    public class BuggyConverter : List<string>, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        => Visibility.Visible;

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) => null;
    }
```

and this into the `MainWindow.xaml`:

```xml
<Window...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BuggyConverter x:Key="conv" Value="{x:Static Brushes.Yellow}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border Visibility="{MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />
        
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Visibility="{MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource conv}}" Width="100" Height="100" Background="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type Brush}">
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" />
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                </x:Array>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Keep `MainWindow.xaml` open and then launch the app via the Start button. You can see a green and a red square. Since this is hardcoded in the XAML, I'd expect the designer to show just that.

Instead, when you exit the app, the designer shows the color hexcodes instead of the colored square, seemingly because it has problems with the converter setup.

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: What is the end result of what you are trying to accomplish?  At the DataTemplate level you are looking at a single item (Brush) but trying to use a MultiBinding?  Are you are trying to override a value in a binding?  (if red then yellow etc)

Comment: @KevinCook This is just a very condensed example. I want to determine if something is enabled depending on multiple properties, which get translated into a single `bool` value through the `MultiBinding`. I don't need help with that, but I would like be to able to preview my template at design-time (which is clearly working at run-time), but the XAML designer somehow gives out.

Comment: You should probably spend some time looking at examples of converters and binding, that this code works (it doesn't actually, but it's like people failing upward at school, the end result happens despite the code being bad).  Your multibinding isn't being bound (hence the error) and your example doesn't even have a way of giving it multiple items to bind to at the level you are trying to use it, since your list only has a single object and not a class of objects, and you are trying to use this at the row level.

Comment: @KevinCook My responses keep getting deleted, no idea by whom. The error is not related to anything you write. Please refrain from posting incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by you is working fine at my end. I think this code that you posted is only meant for StackOverflow and your actual code might be different. Anyway, My educated guess for the null reference exception is that, the public Object value{get; set;}
is getting null each time you try to convert something (in your actual use case scenario)

In case the code that you provided is exactly that you are using then just try to build your project to see if that null reference error
goes away or else try below steps

> 1. Empty your bin/debug folders from such project
> 2. Restart your IDE
> 3. Build your projects

[image]

Comment: Thanks for investiating! I specifically condensed my code as much as possible and even checked it with a fresh WPF project, inserted it, and it's still broken. The issue comes after I close the running apps' window. I'm not even using `Value`! Clearing bin/obj/.vs folders is standard XAML fake error removal procedure I am well aware of. Maybe it just affects my machine... :P

Comment: I just tried it on another PC, even with Resharper installed, same problem. Did you follow the instructions closely? Your XAML designer looks good, mine doesn't show that. The error only occurs after the program closes for the first time.

Comment: @AyCe
Yes, I used the exact code as given and it works for me without any issue. If you want I can attest this into Github and you can download it. Also, you could check the binding or converter that you are using. Perhaps there might be something that's not properly working in those areas.

Comment: If it works for you but the exact same code does not work for me on 2 different machines... what could the problem be? I created fresh solutions and just pasted the code into the files, ran them, and upon closing the window, I got the error both times. You saw the binding and converter. I guess it's just yet another instance of XAML designer strangeness. :( But thank you for testing it!